# Dataframe columns from Dataframe rows in Pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, merge

I have two Pandas DataFrames. I would like to add the rows of the other dataframe as columns in the other. I've tried reading through the Merge, join, and concatenate - documentation, but can't get my head around how to do this in Pandas.

Here's how I've managed to do it with converting to numpy arrays, but surely there is a smart way to do this in Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=8).reshape(4,2),index=[1,2,3,4],columns=['a','b'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=8).reshape(2,4),index=['c','d'],columns=[5,6,7,8])
ar = np.concatenate((df1.values,df2.values.T),axis=1)
df = pd.DataFrame(ar,columns=['a','b','c','d'],index=[1,2,3,4])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `df1.index` has no duplicate values, then you could use `df1.join`:

```
In [283]: df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=8).reshape(4,2),index=[1,2,3,4],columns=['a','b'])

In [284]: df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=8).reshape(2,4),index=['c','d'],columns=[5,6,7,8])

In [285]: df1.join(df2.T.set_index(df1.index))
Out[285]: 
          a         b         c         d
1 -1.196281  0.222283  1.247750 -0.121309
2  1.188098  0.384871 -1.324419 -1.610255
3 -0.928642 -0.618491  0.171215 -1.545479
4 -0.832756 -0.491364  0.100428 -0.525689
```

If `df1` has duplicate entries in its index, then `df1.join(...)` may return more rows than desired. For example, if `df1` has non-unique index `[1,2,1,4]` then:

```
In [4]: df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=8).reshape(4,2),index=[1,2,1,4],columns=['a','b'])

In [5]: df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=8).reshape(2,4),index=['c','d'],columns=[5,6,7,8])

In [8]: df1.join(df2.T.set_index(df1.index))
Out[8]: 
          a         b         c         d
1 -1.087152 -0.828800 -1.129768 -0.579428
1 -1.087152 -0.828800  0.320756  0.297736
1  0.198297  0.277456 -1.129768 -0.579428
1  0.198297  0.277456  0.320756  0.297736
2  1.529188  1.023568 -0.670853 -0.466754
4 -0.393748  0.976632  0.455129  1.230298
```

The 2 rows with index 1 in `df1` are being joined to the 2 rows with index 1 in `df2` resulting in 4 rows with index 1 -- probably not what you want.

So, if `df1.index` does contain duplicate values, use `pd.concat` to guarantee a simple juxtaposition of the two shapes:

```
In [7]: pd.concat([df1, df2.T.set_index(df1.index)], axis=1)
Out[7]: 
          a         b         c         d
1 -1.087152 -0.828800 -1.129768 -0.579428
2  1.529188  1.023568 -0.670853 -0.466754
1  0.198297  0.277456  0.320756  0.297736
4 -0.393748  0.976632  0.455129  1.230298
```

---

One reason you might want to use `df1.join`, however, is that 
if you know `df1.index` has no duplicate values, then using it
is faster than using `pd.concat`:

```
In [13]: df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=8000).reshape(-1,2), columns=['a','b'])

In [14]: df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=8000).reshape(2,-1),index=['c','d'])

In [15]: %timeit df1.join(df2.T.set_index(df1.index))
1000 loops, best of 3: 600 µs per loop

In [16]: %timeit pd.concat([df1, df2.T.set_index(df1.index)], axis=1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.18 ms per loop
```